# Does a stuffed 'Toby the Targ' toy exist?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-ds9

Have you ever seen a stuffed Toby the Targ toy? It was a toy on star trek DS9 and voyager.

If one does exist, where could I find one?

[image: Toby the Targ]

Answer (score 19):

The targ that Molly O'Brien had on ST:DS9 was, in fact, one of ours. It was originally given to Rick Berman by the owner of New Eye Studios. Berman decided to give it to Molly as a fun prop for the show. We also gave one to Michael Dorn, but I have no idea whether he kept it or not.

The targ was modified from a warthog plush toy that was very similar to the one [the other poster referenced](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/48705/20774), as were the other pets we "adopted out". It's nice to know folks have kept them and their adoption certificates!

Comment: Wow, not only a good answer, but an authoritative answer.  Welcome to [scifi.se]!  I should note that the first paragraph belongs as a comment on another answer.

Comment: Do you still produce or sell them? While this has good historical information, the OP seems to be trying to find one currently available for purchase.

Comment: As I posted [below][1] (before my accounts were merged), I don't make them anymore. Sorry.

[1]: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/73013/36212

Comment: Would you have any information on what material the spines on Molly's targ were made of? I bought my daughter the base warthog for Christmas, and now we'd like to convert it to a targ.

Comment: We made molds out of silicone and used a two-part resin kit for the castings, then spray painted the horns. It's been a long time, and I don't remember the name of the companies we dealt with for the materials. Sorry.

Where did you find the warthogs? I didn't think they were making them anymore.

Answer (score 9):

[image]
Here is the one i bought along time ago with the pedigree she gave out with it. I don't know about the licensing The booth I bought it from was a lady who had the two targs and a few animals from one of the paperbacks.....she said she made it, and I have not found any manufacturer tag anywhere on it. could be bought and modified....I never saw another on until the one on the show That was in the O'Brien quarters and since then I have seen one on a site where a guy has one in his collection but he doesn't say where he got it.

Comment: You may want to edit your existing answer, rather than adding a new one - assuming that you're [scott](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/29206/scott).

Comment: Was this a licensed item, or just a fan creation?

Comment: If she said she made it, chances are that it's not licensed and may be harder to find for purchase again.

Comment: You can occasionally find the warthogs on ebay. I bought one for my daughter for Christmas, and I see there is another one up now.

Comment: The tag on the base warthog is: "FUNDAMENTAL TOO, LTD. / 2381 PHILMONT AVE., UNIT C / HUNTINGTON VALLEY, PA, 19006 / (c) 1987 / MADE IN KOREA / SQUEEZEM'S[TM] PATENT PENDING" (front) and "ALL NEW MATERIALS / POLYESTER FIBER / REG. NO. PA. 3339 (K.R.)" (back).

Comment: Just found out that the original warthog is called "Walter Warthog".

Answer (score 6):

Googling "Toby the targ toy" results in [this product on amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000MGN9KA). The colorations and designs are off, but it appears to be the only officially licensed item that was mass produced.

[image: Toby the Targ toy]

It was released with the Star Trek Alien Beans line of toys, which seems to have been a limited run.

[image: Alien Beans Toy Line]

Comment: But Toby has tusks and lacks a unicorn horn. The ears and eyes are also different.

Comment: that really isn't the same thing as the picture...

Answer (score 6):

My daughter and I just finished making one. We found a warthog on ebay matching the "Fascination" DS9 episode. It is called "Walter Warthog", is made by Fundamental Too, is 18 inches from tip of nose to end of tail, and has a grunting mechanism inside. They seem to occasionally show up on ebay. Search for things like *stuffed warthog*, *plush warthog*, *Walter warthog* or *warthog Fundamental*. We then bought some plushy upholstery fabric for the spines (the fabric store was happy to sell us 1/8 of a yard), sewed spines (sewing machine, but could also be done by hand), flipped them inside out, stuffed them and sewed them on.

It was surprisingly harder than it seemed: flipping heavy-weight fabric inside-out was hard and sewing the spines amidst the fur isn't easy (hint: use a curved needle).

Full instructions as well as a pdf with our sewing patterns are [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Toby-the-Targ-From-Star-Trek/).

[image: Toby the Targ]

Comment: You did a nice job! But I think the silicone horns were easier to work with. LOL! We just shaved a bit of the hair off, then glued the spikes to the fabric, gluing some of the fur to the spikes to help hold them in place.

Answer (score 4):

I thought it would be nice to post a photo of some of my babies from years ago. Hopefully, I can get it right this time! I tried a link last time, but it didn't work.

[image: my targ puppies]

Comment: Where did you get these from?

Comment: I made them. A friend and I used to make and sell baby targs, mugatus, crystal singers, Capellan power cats, and sehlats in the early to mid-90s. We were in New York at the time, but sold to dealers who travelled all around the country.

Comment: Instead of creating a second account and second answer, you should log in and edit your old answer.

Comment: I don't make any of the creatures anymore. Sorry. I've only got one left of each kind for my personal collection. I'm not even sure the company we purchased the warthogs from even makes them anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The toy actually exists, but it looks like what they used for *Toby the Targ* was a warthog plush.

I doubt they still make the exact toy that was filmed, but
[this is close](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Adventure-Planet-8-Warthog-Plush-/201015993409). It is an ebay link.

Answer (score 0):

I have one....just like the screen used one....bought it in ther 90's at a convention in D.C. a fan had a booth and she made them supposedly.......she had two at the time and I bought 1 remember it was 50 dollars.  I will post a picture of it on Thursday when I return to work!

Comment: Post a picture!

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a answer, it doesn't appear to me to answer the question.

Comment: @iliveunderawesomerock Technically this answers part of the question: "Does such a Targ-Toy exist?" Answer: "Yes it does, scott has one." Only the "where can I find one"-part is not addressed.